# De Moivre Formula question

Tags: complex-numbers

why does  $64e^{i3π}$  = $-64$? Im not really sure how this follows from the De Moivre formula..Is there a trigonometric proof of this?

Comment: Do you know the formula $$e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$$ If so, just set $x = 3\pi$ and compute.

Comment: Eulers identity?

Comment: You can use $e^{i\pi}=-1$ and $(-1)^3=-1$

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying a complex number by $e^{i\theta}$ rotates the number by an angle of $\theta$ in anti-clockwise direction about the origin in complex plane.

So, multiplying $64$ with $e^{i3\pi}$ rotates it by angle of $3\pi$ around origin in complex plane leaving it at $-64$.

Answer (score 0):

Euler's Identity:

$$e^{i3\pi} = cos(3\pi) + isin(3\pi) = -1+i0$$

Now $$64e^{i3\pi} = 64(cos(3\pi) + isin(3\pi)) = -1*64 = -64.$$